# EmailAddressAttribute validation rules

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, regex, data-annotations

I have been using the EmailAddressAttribute (from System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations) in my code and it has been working great.  The BA's and Testers need to know the rules about how it validates an email address.  I can make head nor tail of the regex as it is 900 characters long and my regex skills are limited.

Can anyone explain the rules to me in simple terms?

Comment: Your testers should create their own test cases for emails they think should pass and fail.  What's the purpose of telling the tester only what will work?  They should only be concerned about it can do what it advertises it can do, not how it accomplishes it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, in an email address string, you have texts before and after "@" sign.

Each character in texts should match 2 rules:

1. `` [a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'*+-/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF] ``
2. some unicode code rules as I listed below.

The first rule means a char in text can be one of the following:

- a-z
- any digit
- one of `` !#\$%&'*+-/=\?\^_`{\|}~ ``
- in unicode range `\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF`

Then texts are separated by `.`

---

It should be something like:

```
private static Regex _regex = new Regex(@"^
(
    (
        ([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+
        (\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*
    )
    |
    (
        (\x22)
        (
        (((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?
        (
            ([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|
            (\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))
        )
        )*
        (((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)
    )
)

@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
```

Comment: I think he was after a more concise explanation of this particular expression